# Use a WFS-T layer in d3.js without adding a background map?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson, wfs-t, d3

I am currently working on a d3.js project and would like to include a WFS-T layer to my SVG map to display *and* update location data stored in a PostGIS database. I know that I need to transform my layer to a geoJSON format for d3.js to be able to read the data. But this would mean that I break my WFS-T logic and I am not able to update my data (?). Also I don't want to add a background map (e.g. from openlayers) to the map. Finally I need to display the data on a globe ([like this](http://bl.ocks.org/ivyywang/7c94cb5a3accd9913263)), which is another reason I cannot use openlayers.

Can anybody point me to a strategy how to solve this?